# Colorir uma linha caso uma condição seja verdadeira

Tags: excel-vba

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Set range1 = Range("B2:B20")


For Each cell In range1
    If cell = "Recente" Then
        With cell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
       
       
    ElseIf cell = "Retornado" Then
       With cell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
       End With
       
       
    ElseIf cell = "Antigo" Then
        
        With cell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
       End With
       
       
    ElseIf cell = "Caducado" Then
        With cell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
       End With
       
    ElseIf cell = "" Then
       With cell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
       
       
    End If
    
 Next
 
End Sub
```

Em minha planilha de excel eu possui uma coluna de status com as seguintes opções: "Retornado", "Antigo", "Caducado" e "Recente". A tabela como um todo possuí o seguinte `Range ("A1:L16")`, a coluna com status possuí o seguinte `Range ("B1:B16")`. O codigo consiste em colorir, com determinada coloração, as celulas da culana de status para cada tipo de status presentes nela. Eu gostaria de coloria a linha como um todo, e não apenas a celula.

Exemplo:

> Range Tabela ("A1:L16").

> Range Coluna de Status ("B1:B16").

Obs: A tabela possui cabeçalho no range ("A1:L1").

Quando a celula ("B3") fosse alterada para o status "Retornado", a coloração do Range ("A3:L3") fosse alterado para cor definida dentro do bloco WITH que fica na IF statement desse status.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, é só colocar a Letra e numero inicial da coluna e a Letra e numero final da coluna.
Exp: Pintar toda a Linha 2

Range ("B2:L2")